# Http failure response for https:/xxxxxxx/api/auth/register: 0 Unknown Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Currently, I am using an ASP.NET Core server with an Angular client. I am encountering an issue with the POST function, and below is the error message:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsl3.png)

However, I don't have any problems with the GET function. I have asked for help multiple times and learned that the issue is related to CORS. I have already configured the CORS settings as shown below, but it is still not working:

[ConfigureServices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p43ig.png)

[Configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCMs1.png)

Comment: I cant believe im asking this, but are you sending a POST request ? Sometimes you can get a CORS error and the error has nothing to do with CORS.

Also, please provide some code for us to be able to debug